# Calculating the minimal polynomial of linear combinations of numbers

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I am trying to calculate the minimal polynomial of $\theta^2/2$, where $\theta$ is a root of $X^3-2X-2$ (I'm trying to work out if $\theta^2/2$ is an algebraic integer in $\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$). I have approached this the same way I approached $\theta/2$, writing $\theta^2/2$ as a linear combination of $1,\theta^2/2, (\theta/2)^2$, and $(\theta^2/2)^3$, but i have gotten stuck. Some help would be appreciated!

Comment: You'll need $(\theta^2/2)^3$ too.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to include that in my post, I couldn't have found the minimal polynomial for $\theta/2$ in that way either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide $a (\theta^2/2)^3 + b (\theta^2/2)^2 + c (\theta^2/2) + d$ by $\theta^3 - 2 \theta - 2$.  The remainder will be a polynomial of degree $2$ in $\theta$,
which must be $0$.    Solve the system of three equations for the coefficients.

Comment: Why do we know that the remainder has to be zero?

Comment: Because you want this polynomial to be $0$ when $\theta^3 - 2 \theta - 2 = 0$.

Comment: Is there a quicker algorithm for working this out, since this method doesn't seem particularly pleasant for $\frac{1+\theta+\theta^2}{2}$?